# How to derive the discrete delta function from geometric sum of complex sinusoids?

Tags: exponential-sum

Using this in the context of Fourier transforms. This should probably be an easy derivation for you guys, but I forget how to derive it.

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{L-1}e^{-j\frac{2\pi k}{L}n} = \frac{1-e^{-j2\pi k}}{1-e^{\frac{-j2\pi k}{L}}}
$$

which somehow can also be reduced to $$L\delta [k] $$

Comment: Write the thing inside the sum as $u^n$, where $u = \exp(-2j\pi k/L)$. Then it's just a sum of a geometric series.

Comment: Gah, yes I see it now. Any hints about the reduction to the discrete delta function?

Comment: Nope --- none whatsoever. if you actually want people to address that as well, it'd be useful to say so in your question rather than just adding it as an after-the-fact note.

Comment: true, I made the update. Thanks for helping with the first half, though.

Comment: Is the term inside the summation $e^{-j \frac{2 \pi k n}{L}}$? (i.e. missing $n$?)

Answer (score 2):

When $k=0$, the summation is simply $L$.

For $k \neq 0$, write the numerator as: $e^{-j \pi k} \left( e^{j \pi k} - e^{-j \pi k} \right)$ = $e^{-j \pi k} \times 2j \sin(k \pi)$, which is $0$ for $k \neq 0$, because $\sin(k \pi)=0$.

Thus, you have a summation which is $L$ for $k=0$ and $0$ for $k \neq 0$. This can be expressed as $L \delta[k]$.

Also, the denominator should read $1- e^{-j \frac{2 \pi k}{L}}$.